# Encoding URL GET variable

Tags: javascript, html, get

I want to ask you how can I safely encode multiple GET variables from my URL and put them in one, then it send it to another page.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Encoding or Encrypting?

Comment: are you perhaps looking for javascript's uri encoding tools?

encodeURIComponent('hello / world : = ')
"hello%20%2F%20world%20%3A%20%3D%20"

Comment: Encode. Sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to **increase security** of the data being sent through URL then **you should go for `POST` method instead of `GET`**. Otherwise if you are bound to use `GET` then use some **encryption(*A way of encoding*) standards** e.g. **MD5** on the data before you put them in the URL using `GET` method.

There are functionalities available on server side that can be used for the encryption.